# Error 'AttributeError' in python

Tags: python

I have that error in python with requests, web scraping!:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import *

base_url = 'https://www.vagas.com.br/'
jobsurl = f'{base_url}/vagas-em-recife'
requestsjob = get(jobsurl)
requestsjob_bs = bs(requestsjob.text, 'html.parser')
vagas = requestsjob_bs.find('a', class_='link-detalhes-vaga').get_text()

for vaga in vagas:
    titulo_vaga = vagas.find('a').text
    print(titulo_vaga)
```

Error:

```
titulo_vaga = vagas.find('a').text
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Aqui é o stackoverflow em português. Você pode traduzir a pergunta para português ou refazer a pergunta no stackoverflow em ingles.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando `get_text()` e funções `.text`.
Removi `get_text()` do seu código e inseri `get("title")` no seu loop.
Tente esse código.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import *

base_url = 'https://www.vagas.com.br/'
jobsurl = f'{base_url}/vagas-em-recife'
requestsjob = get(jobsurl)
requestsjob_bs = bs(requestsjob.text, 'html.parser')
vagas = requestsjob_bs.findAll('a', class_='link-detalhes-vaga')

for vaga in vagas:
    titulo_vaga = vaga.get("title")
    print(titulo_vaga)
```